# AngularJS & xeditable $http.post not updating scope return data

Tags: php, angularjs

I am trying to achieve this: http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/3951/

However, with the added complication of updating a database. All working apart from the 'Add' functionality. I have changed this:

```
// add user
$scope.addUser = function() {
    $scope.inserted = {
        id: $scope.users.length + 1,
        name: '',
        status: null,
        group: null
    };
    $scope.users.push($scope.inserted);
};
```

into this:

```
    $scope.addRow = function() {
        $code = Math.floor(Math.random() * (9999 - 1000) + 1000);
        $scope.inserted = {
            id: '',
            code: $code,
            description: '',
            location: ''
        };
        return $http.post('php/add.php', $scope.inserted).
        success(function(response) {
            $scope.inserted = response;
            $scope.parts.push($scope.inserted);
        });
    };
```

The data is added to the database with no problems, however, although the form appears, it does not contain the id (auto incremented PK) & code. It needs to do this (certainly the id) so that when the 'save' button is clicked, the 'edit.php' page knows which row to update with changes.

Can anyone enlighten me as to why my `$http.post().success` is not returning data? I assume that is the problem.

Comment: Is the server responding with the updated item with an id? Check the http request to see what the server responded with and/or put a breakpoint in the success callback to see what angular is getting as a response.

Comment: The server's response has the json data that I want. Not sure how to go about adding a breakpoint but I will look into tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: Try `console.log` on your response. Your object may be wrapped without you realizing it. Additionally, add an error handler (`.error(function (err) {})`) to your `$http` chain to make sure it's not hitting that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted! Thanks both for your help, I don't know if one or both of you would like to post an answer so you can receive your deserved kudos? Jedd was bang on when he said that the object was wrapped. It was inside an array. I simply changed my code to:

```
$scope.addRow = function() {
$code = Math.floor(Math.random() * (9999 - 1000) + 1000);
    $scope.inserted = { 
        id: '99',
        code: $code,
        description: '',
        location: '' 
    };
return $http.post('php/add.php', $scope.inserted).
    success(function(response) {
        $scope.inserted = response[0];
        $scope.parts.push($scope.inserted);
    });
};
```

*Note that it's*

```
$scope.inserted = response[0];
```

*that makes all the difference!*